# MATLAB sine wave plot is not correct

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am new to MATLAB and I wrote some code to generate a sine wave. However the graph is not correct.  Here is the screenshot of my code and the plot

[image: MATLAB]

What is the problem? Please help!

Comment: If you can screenshot your code you can copy and paste it here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MATLAB plots **discrete** points and simply draws a straight line to connect neighbouring points together.  Your time points are one second (1s) in between, and you are specifying a frequency of 100 Hz.  In addition, because your sampling time is a multiple of the period of your sine wave, substituting all of those values of `t` would thus make the `sin` result equal to 0, though there is some numerical imprecision.  Specifically, if you look at the y-axis, you'll see that the magnitude of your numbers is around `10^{-13}`.  However even if you escape this, the sampling time is TOO LARGE for the specified frequency of your wave and so this huge gap in between points is visualized as that jagged wave that you see in your graph.

The solution is to simply make your sampling time smaller.  Try something small, like `1e-4` for example:

```
t = 0:1e-4:0.05;
f = 100;
A = 2;
x = A*sin(2*pi*f*t);
plot(t,x);
```

We get this now:

[image]

Comment: Requested 10000000001x1 (74.5GB) array exceeds
maximum array size preference. Creation of
arrays greater than this limit may take a long
time and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive.
See array size limit or preference panel for
more information.

Error in new1 (line 2)
t=0:1e-10:1;

Comment: @nehal_b Changed the sampling time. I made it too small.

Comment: @rayryengThe plot is continuously increase and nowhere near sine wave :(

Comment: @nehal_b Uh... it's a sine wave.  I'll upload a plot.

Comment: @nehal_b I would suggest understanding the mathematical output of your equation and then paying attention to the limits of your axes and how they compare to the expected output...